# punctuation ereg_replace preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, replace, punctuation, ereg

I have this snippet of code from an old OsCommerce install

```
    $pattern = $this->attributes['SEO_REMOVE_ALL_SPEC_CHARS'] == 'true'
                    ?   "([^[:alnum:]])+"
                    :   "([[:punct:]])+";
```

I would like to modify the [:punct:] selector so it excludes the - dash.

next line of code is

```
$anchor = ereg_replace($pattern, '', strtolower($string));
```

which removes the previously found characters. how can I keep my dashes?

Thanks, Mario

**EDIT**

I think i got it:

```
$pattern = $this->attributes['SEO_REMOVE_ALL_SPEC_CHARS'] == 'true'
                    ?   "([^[:alnum:]])+"
                    :   "([^-a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]])+";
```

note: the dash has to come first. or, for underscores:

```
$pattern = $this->attributes['SEO_REMOVE_ALL_SPEC_CHARS'] == 'true'
                    ?   "([^[:alnum:]])+"
                    :   "([^a-zA-Z0-9_[:space:]])+";
```

I didn't figure out how to use negative lookaheads :(.
Cheers. Mario

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to make your own `[characterset]` instead of using `[:punct:]`.

This one looks about right, but you'll need to verify it.

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9-\s]
```

This will replace anything that is not an (a-z) letter, digit, white space, or dash.

```
$pattern = $this->attributes['SEO_REMOVE_ALL_SPEC_CHARS'] == 'true'
            ?   "([^[:alnum:]])+"
            :   "[^a-zA-Z0-9-\s]+";
```

**Edit: Old answer**, that **won't work** because [ereg doesn't support lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html).

Try this negative lookahead `(?!-)`:

```
$pattern = $this->attributes['SEO_REMOVE_ALL_SPEC_CHARS'] == 'true'
                ?   "([^[:alnum:]])+"
                :   "((?!-)[[:punct:]])+";
```